# Replacement producing unexpected result

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

If I use a replacement rule like

```
Times[2, Plus[Times[AuRr, BuRb], Times[AuRb, BuRr]], h10] /. 
  {Times[r_, Plus[Times[x_, y_], Times[v_, w_]], h10] :> 
     r*TensorProduct[(TensorProduct[x, y] + TensorProduct[v, w]), h10]}
```

I get correctly

```
(* 2 (AuRb \[TensorProduct] BuRr + AuRr \[TensorProduct] BuRb) \[TensorProduct]h10 *)
```

Nevertheless, if I try to do the same thing more general, i.e. allowing for a general last coefficient, not specifically h10:

```
Times[2, Plus[Times[AuRr, BuRb], Times[AuRb, BuRr]], h10] /. 
  {Times[r_, Plus[Times[x_, y_], Times[v_, w_]], h_] :> 
    r*TensorProduct[(TensorProduct[x, y] + TensorProduct[v, w]), h]}
```

I get the wrong result

```
 (* 2 h10 (AuRb \[TensorProduct] BuRr + AuRr \[TensorProduct] BuRb) *)
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong here, would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't add bugs tag until the community has conformed it. BTW it's almost impossible to find a bug in core language of Mathematica.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica automatically factors out constants from `TensorProduct`s:

```
TensorProduct[a, 2 b] (* returns 2 a\[TensorProduct]b *)
```

If you consider

```
Times[2, Plus[Times[AuRr, BuRb], Times[AuRb, BuRr]], h10] /. 
 {Times[r_, Plus[Times[x_, y_], Times[v_, w_]], h_] 
  :> 
  Echo[r]*TensorProduct[(TensorProduct[x, y] + TensorProduct[v, w]), Echo@h]
 }
```

you will see that the pattern-matcher sets `r = h10` and `h = 2`, which accounts for why the constants end up outside the expression. Then it ends up with a `TensorProduct` of an expression with `1`, and that gets rid of the outermost `TensorProduct`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I now simply add the condition /; Element[r, Reals] and everything works perfectly