# How to force a replacement in an order that I want?

Tags: replacement, rule

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103000/replacement-producing-unexpected-result).

I have a big sum, with lots of terms of the form

```
Times[Complex[0, Rational[-1, 4]], Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]], Aurb, Bdrb, h[3]]
```

Each term in the sum consists of five objects, 2 numbers, one h[i] and an object starting with A, e.g. Aurb and an object starting with B, as for example, Bdrb.

I want to transform every term such that I have only terms of the form

```
Times[ComplexNumber, RealNumber, h[i], KroneckerProduct[A..., B...]],
```

for the term above

```
Times[Complex[0, Rational[-1, 4]], Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]], h[3], KroneckerProduct[Aurb, Bdrb]]
```

The important thing is that always the `A...` and `B...` are put into the `KroneckerProduct`. How can I tell the *Mathematica* to always replace my terms like this? Ideally, I want that *Mathematica* checks for all elements that are part of a given list, for example `MemberQ[All my objects starting with A, ...]` and put it then at the correct spot in the replacement rule.

Comment: Why do you have ellipses (...) after the `A` and `B` variables? Are there sometimes more than one of each of the variables showing up? By the way, the matching would be a *lot* easier if you decided to name the variables with `Head`s `a` and `b` instead: for instance, use `a[urb]` and `b[drb]` instead of `aurb` and `bdrb`. Then, this expression manipulation will be much easier to do.

Comment: @march Thanks for your comment. The ellipses denote rest of the name for this object. I did not number them as the h[i], but there is always only one of each object. Given a better naming, as for example a[urb], how could replacement rule be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

```
fun = Times[Complex[0, Rational[-1, 4]], Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]], Aurb, Bdrb, h[3]];

Times @@ Complement[List @@ fun, #] KroneckerProduct @@ # &[Cases[fun, _Symbol]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With

```
foo = Times[Complex[0, Rational[-1, 4]], Power[2, Rational[-1, 2]], Aurb, Bdrb, h[3]]
```

Then

```
foo /. (a_Symbol b_Symbol) -> KroneckerProduct[a, b]
```

If you want to be more strict on the name of the symbols then

```
foo /. ((a_Symbol /; StringTake[SymbolName@a, 1] == "A") 
        (b_Symbol /; StringTake[SymbolName@b, 1] == "B")) -> KroneckerProduct[a, b]
```

Hope this helps